# jsx (Reactjs) lint for Visual Studio Code?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, lint

What is best ReactJs lint for Visual Studio Code???
I am searching and I just can't find good lint when I working with ReactJs. 
Please help.

Thank you :D

Comment: What is the problem with `ESLint`? It even has Visual Studio formatter?

Comment: This is what I got "No ESLint configuration (e.g .eslintrc) found for file: public\app.jsx
File will not be validated. Consider running the 'Create .eslintrc.json file' command.
Alternatively you can disable ESLint for this workspace by executing the 'Disable ESLint for this workspace' command."

Comment: Ok, so you failed to configure a linter and instead of fixing the config you are looking for a different linter?

Comment: Sorry I am new to programming, I just start with ReactJs. Do you know how to configure ESLint?